# Blocking until condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a class called `_NodeProcess`. It consists of a mainloop (`main` function) which is run in a separate process and methods (`start` and `stop`) that control the mainloop. Here's the code:

```
class _NodeProcess:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.main)
        self.is_alive = True
        self.is_dead = False

    def start(self):
        self.process.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.is_alive = False
        while not self.is_dead:
            pass

    def main(self):
        while self.is_alive:
            task = self.master.give_task()
            self.master.grab_result({'header': 'result', 'result': self.master.function(task), 'task': task})
        self.is_dead = True
```

The part that worries me is the `stop` function. On each mainloop iteration, I check whether I should continue (`self.is_alive == True`), and if I shouldn't, I stop and do `self.is_dead = True` to confirm that i had quit the loop. Meanwile, in the `stop` function, after setiing `self.is_alive` to `False`, and block until `self.is_dead == True`.

My concern is the way in which I block:

```
while not self.is_dead:
    pass
```

I'm afraid it may eat to much resources just iterating over that loop at a very high speed. So, I considered another option, using `time.sleep`:

```
import time

while not self.is_dead:
    time.sleep(1)
```

But it doesn't seem like a best way to block until some condition is met (I need an extra library; I lose 0.5 seconds on average when I call the `stop` method, if I make the period less, I spend more resources, so it's some kind of a compromise, which has to be made each time I write code like that). Is there a better solution for this particular problem, or maybe it's better to redesign the class in some way that would allow not facing this problem at all?

Comment: You need real synchronization. Look at `multiprocessing.Lock` and/or `multiprocessing.Condition`. Playing with `time.sleep()` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I realized that I can just call `self.process.join()` and to me it seems the best solution in this particular situation (waiting for thread to finish), though, thank you for your adivice, now I see I need to learn more about thread synchronization, because in a common situation when I need to wait for some other thing to happen, I'll need it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `self.is_dead`. You simply need to block until the thread is complete. For that, we have [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join):

```
def stop(self):
    self.is_alive = False
    self.process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I must preface with the fact that I know little about multiprocessing. However, I do know that for a `while` loop of that format using `time`, it doesn't particularly matter what you set it to.

On my system, the code:

```
While 1:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

still uses an undetectable (0.0%) amount of CPU, in comparison with `time.sleep(1)`. Even `time.sleep(.01)` only uses .4% of my CPU. There are likely better solutions that have to do specifically with that library, but this is likely the simplest.

Comment: Yes, it does use a little cpu, and really works, but the problem that bothered me was that I have to choose the time. And I have no idea how to choose between 0.1 and 0.01 for example, so, when I finally write some number in there, I can't be sure I chose the right one. That doesn't feel as a good programming practice:) And also, I have to import an extra library, which is also not so great.